# Is SDL2 alone capable of dynamic (or deferred) lighting?

Tags: sdl, deferred-rendering

I'm talking about JUST SDL2, not OpenGL or DirectX.
Would drawing deferred lighting bulk the CPU up and how would it be done?

Comment: I am not sure you know what you are asking about

Comment: I think I know what I'm asking about. I've never seen deferred lighting done primarily with SDL2, it always seems to be with DX or OGL. --> How is it done primarily with SDL2?

Comment: Deferred lighting is typically a 3D thing that's all about simplifying the GPU lighting pipeline run on the GPU and SDL2 does not do 3D rendering or expose shaders without using OGL or D3D. It's still unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: deferred lighting (I believe also called light pre pass) is just a way of performing lighting by buffering some things in special textures so you can do some optimizations in the lighting stage. It has nothing to do with SDL or any other high level API, its something you implement using OpenGL / DX or other equivalent API I am not aware of. As far as I know, SDL doesn't implement that kind of rendering optimization as SDL isn't a full blown game engine, and rather leaves these things to users.. And you probably mean't to ask about deferred rendering, not lighting :p

Comment: I gave you an answer, but I also downvoted because it doesn't lead to anything but "you need to actually learn the basics of graphics programming before implementing something like deferred rendering".

Answer (score 1):

SDL2 provides no facilities for computing lighting, so yes, if you don't use shaders through OpenGL, D3D, etc. to do deferred rendering, or rendering a scene of any complexity for that matter, you're going to leave all that [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) and SIMD work to the CPU.

The concept is exactly the same whether you're doing it on the GPU or the CPU.  Instead of summing each light's contribution in a loop over the objects, you're summing each object's contribution in a loop over the lights (where much of the object's data is cached using the G-buffer).

What you should get out of this is that **you don't want to do any sort of 3D rendering without hardware acceleration**, which on the PC requires you to use either OpenGL or D3D.